# How do you send vim to the background from a terminal window?

Tags: terminal-buffer, job-control

I just learned that Vim has the `:terminal` command, which opens a window with a terminal session inside. Previously, my normal workflow was to launch vim from my terminal and use job control to get in and out of it (i.e. edit files, use `<C-z>` to put vim in the background, interact with my shell, then use `fg` to bring vim back to the foreground, then keep editing files).

Now that I know about `:term`, it would be nice to incorporate it into my workflow. However, I require the ability to still be able to use the workflow mentioned above. The problem is, `<C-z>` inside the terminal window inside vim gets interpreted by that window's shell. According to `:help terminal-typing`, using `<C-w> N` will enter Terminal-Normal mode. From there I can use `<C-z>` like I am used to doing. However, after I get back into vim, the terminal is still in Terminal-Normal mode, and I need to manually enter Terminal mode (using `i` or `a` or whatever).

Is there a way to send vim to the background from within a terminal window in such a way that leaves the terminal in Terminal mode? I'd like to set up some mappings such that I can treat the terminal window splits just like other vim windows seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> to enter Ex mode from the terminal, then use the `:suspend` command to suspend Vim (same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> typically does.)

When you come back to Vim using `fg`, you'll be on your Vim terminal, which will be already in insert mode (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> only enters Ex mode for a single command.)

If you want to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal to suspend Vim (instead of suspending whatever foreground program the shell in the terminal is running), you can add the following mapping to your vimrc:

```
tnoremap <C-z> <C-w>:suspend<CR>
```

That way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on a terminal will behave the same as it behaves in a normal Vim buffer.